# How can I select a node in a JTree from an xpath expression?

Tags: java, xpath, jtree

In Java, how can I select a node in a JTree from an xpath expression?

**Input**: XPath Expression

**Output**: node corresponding to that XPath expression is selected in the JTree

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does the `JTree` represent a xml document? The answer is probably no or not likey

Comment: The JTree was loaded from an xml document.

Comment: You "might" be able to build a `TreePath` from the results of the xpath query against the original document, but you're going to need to be able to match each node in the xml document to a node in the `JTree` to make it work. Basically, one you have the result of the query, you can walk back up it's hierarchy, which will allow you to build the path you will need